# Un nouveau site SE pour le français

Tags: support, site-evaluation, area51, site-promotion

Il y a plusieurs site concernant la langue anglaise, par exemple :

- [English language](https://english.stackexchange.com/) qui ressemble à ce site.
- [English learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions) qui aussi ressemble à ce site.
- [Science fiction & fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/).
- [Literature](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).
- [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/)

J'ai proposé [un nouveau site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122300/redaction?referrer=0BZTyF7-wJtLURtU5SdaJw2) sur area 51. Ce site, appelé *Rédaction*, ressemble plus-ou-moins aux deux derniers sites anglais. C'est un lieu, pas pour apprendre le français au niveau élémentaire, mais pour le métier d'écriture professionnelle, y compris la fiction, non-fiction, technique, l'écriture scientifique et commerciale. C'est aussi un site pour les érudits et les passionnés de littérature. Un utilisateur peut demander des conseils sur la rédaction et la publication ou bien poster un petit texte et demander de le critiquer.

Supportez-vous un tel site?

Comment: *Science fiction & fantasy* and *Literature* are definitely not sites about English or exclusively about English content.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe They are mostly in English.

Comment: Those sites are *entirely* in English, but what you wrote is that they are *about* English ("concernant la *langue* anglaise"), which is not true.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe They are almost always about english. There's more than 8900 questions on literature.SE and only 55 of them are about french literature: that makes 0.6% of the questions. Combining all languages (other than english) we get probably less than 10%.

Comment: I've been trying to get more questions on non-English literature on Literature SE, especially by suggestion reading challenges of French (e.g. [Guy de Maupassant](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1185/2191)), German and other authors. But the success of these proposals depends on part on participants who don't necessarily read literature in English.

Comment: Je trouve curieux de donner le nom area51 à un site français. Il n'y a rien de "plus américain" que area51.

Comment: "Area 51 is the Stack Exchange Network staging zone, where users come together to build new Q&A sites. New site ideas are proposed, discussed, and the best go on to beta. See the faq for more information. "

Answer (score 12):

Malheureusement [Stack Exchange refuse la création de nouveaux sites non anglophones](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack).

Il y a certainement un créneau à prendre. Le principe des questions-réponses, intermédiaire entre l'encyclopédie qui est limitée à des sujets bien définis et le forum de discussion où l'information est quasi-introuvable après coup, a très bien montré son utilité. Étant donné que l'histoire de l'extension de Stack Exchange au-delà de l'anglais consiste en [9 ans](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/how-can-i-propose-a-non-english-site/53004#53004) [de promesses](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82176/localization-the-state-of-the-nation/82229#82229) [non tenues](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition), il ne faut pas compter sur SE pour remplir ce créneau.

Sur le sujet « rédaction » en particulier, je ne pense pas qu'un site commun pour ceux qui lisent et ceux qui écrivent marche vraiment. Ce sont des communautés qui se rencontrent trop peu. Si le sujet était restreint à la littérature, ce serait viable, mais il y a trop de distance entre l'analyse littéraire et la rédaction technique. De plus, je pense que le titre est mal choisi : « rédaction » fait penser à un exercice scolaire et n'attirera ni les écrivains, ni les rédacteurs techniques, ni les critiques littéraires.